# Add text to TextFrame in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I am automating the creation of a PowerPoint using C++/CLI and .Net. I have a textbox on my slide and want to add text, but there is a build error every time. Here is my code:

```
System::String^ hi = "hello";
slides[1]->Shapes[1]->TextFrame->TextRange->Text::set(hi);
```

The build error is this:

```
error C2653: 'Text' : is not a class or namespace name
```

I have looked up the error but cannot seem to figure what I am doing wrong. If I were to be using C# it seems as through I would do:

```
TextRange.Text = "Hello";
```

So I tried to do:

```
TextRange->Text = "Hi";
```

But it threw the build error of:

```
error C3293: 'Text': use 'default' to access the default property (indexer) for class 'Microsoft::Office::Interop::PowerPoint::TextRange'
```

How would I set the text? The syntax for `Text`, according to MSDN, in C++ is:

```
public:
property String^ Text {
String^ get ();
void set (String^ value);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default properties have a fairly long history of being troublesome.  They provide nice syntax sugar, you don't have to name them, but they cause rotten teeth because of the ambiguity they can create.  The reason for the Set keyword in VBA.  If you use Set then you assign the TextRange property, if you don't or use Let then you assign the default property.

.NET supports default properties as well but got rid of the syntax ambiguity by requiring that the default property takes an argument.  Which resolves the ambiguity, the compiler can tell that you meant the default property if the argument is present.  Such a property is called the "indexer".  The List<> class is a good example, the indexer is documented as the "Item" property but you don't actually write its name.  You use syntax like `list[0]` to index the first item.  Very convenient, it allows you to treat the list like an array in your code.

The PowerPoint TextRange::Text property causes trouble because it is the default property of the TextRange interface but does *not* take an argument.  So you can't use "Text" since it is the default property name and you can't omit it either because it is not an indexer.  You fix that just as the error message says you do, use the *default* keyword:

```
System::String^ hi = "hello";
slides[1]->Shapes[1]->TextFrame->TextRange->default = hi;
```